# jQuery popup div fades out after fading in

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV element right at the beginning of my HTML code

```
<div id="popup"></div>
```

Its CSS `display` property is set to `none` initially. Now when I click on specific HTML elements, the following happens:

```
$('#popup-opener-button').click(function() {
    $('#popup').fadeIn();
});
```

This works like charm. Now I'd like this DIV to disappear whenever I click anywhere on the screen, except when clicking on the DIV itself. I thought this would do it:

```
$('#popup').siblings().click(function() {
    $('#popup').fadeOut();
});
```

but as the SPAN I'm clicking on to fade in my popup div is actually the child of #popup's sibling, it instantly fades out right after fading in. Is there a way not to do this?

Comment: A bit confusing -- can you edit the markup you've shown to include this span you refer to?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how well this would perform in a heavy DOM as there would be an awful lot of event bubbling going on and the `:not` psuedoselector isn't the fastest, but this method uses the selector that you can pass to `.on( )` to filter out `div#popup`, essentially allowing you to click anything else on the page to trigger your `fadeOut()`.

```
​$(document.body).on('click',':not(#popup)', function(){ $('#popup').fadeOut(); })​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're hoping to click on `#popup` if it's initially hidden. Is this a mistake in your code?

This is a solution that works for me.

```
$('#popup').click(function(e) {
    $('#popup').fadeIn();

    // if i click in the popup, don't bubble the event up to the 'body' 
    e.stopPropagation();

    // hook up the fade-out event to the body to handle a click anywhere else
    $('body').one('click', function () { $('#popup').fadeOut(); });
});
```

Comment: My bad, sorry. I didn't have the original code at hand so I couldn't copy-paste. I'll try this whenever I get to my computer.